# React onClick event on link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this weird thing i have this simple component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
const Logo = ({onClick}) => {
return (

    <a name="home" onClick={onClick} className="logo">

        <span className="logo-mini"></span>



    </a>

);
};


export default Logo;
```

the onClick event suppose to to get the click event on the link to get attribute name but what i got is undefined when i console.log the `event.target` the out put is `<span class="logo-lg"></span>`

in the root compenent my render methode call `<Logo onClick={this.handleClick}/>`
handleClick method

```
    handleClick(){
    let to = event.target.name;
    console.log(event.target);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the desired attribute by chaining `parentElement` with the `getAttribute()` method. 
Try this in you `handleClick` method
**`console.log(event.target.parentElement.getAttribute('name'));`**

More info here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement

Alternatively, you could use: 
`console.log(event.target.getAttribute('name'));`
but this would require that you put the `name` attribute on your `span` element.

Also, in case the gist gets deleted, here is a full working code:

```
class Header extends React.Component { 
  handleClick(event) {
    console.log(event.target.parentElement.getAttribute('name'));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Logo onClick={this.handleClick}/>
    );
  }
}

const Logo = ({onClick}) => {
  return (
    <a name="home" onClick={onClick} className="logo">
        <span className="logo-mini">Logo</span>
    </a>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Header/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Link to codepen: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/LRRYRq

Comment: its work like this thanks, but why onClick event on <a ...</a> get me <span > ?, just to understand the problem

Comment: This is just another option. Both solutions will work. Adding `name` on the `span` element instead of the `a` element would just save you from using the `parentElement` property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind this to your function call.

```
 <Logo onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}/>
```

Comment: I did that in my constructor this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this) and i tried like you did but the same result

Comment: can u share your components once? Both parent and child, really difficult to figure this out without that

Comment: a gist for the parent and the child [link](https://gist.github.com/smidaamine/d4700f18e61c5a5459fab332fddfbc63)